# A value of 'List<Homes>?' can't be assigned to a variable of type'List<Homes>'

Tags: flutter

why it doesn't work, it worked fine in without null safety something might be missed.
but I don't understand what's wrong
It would be great help if you give some time to this

```
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.hasData) {
                List<Homes> homelist = snapshot.data;
                return new CustomListView(homelist);
              } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
                return Text('${snapshot.error}');
              }
              //return  a circular progress indicator.
              return new CircularProgressIndicator();
            },
          ),
```

Comment: declare variable like this final List<Homes>? homelist;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not working anymore because now you have **null safety** on.

With it, variables cannot be null if they haven't got a `?` at the end. For example:

```
String myString = "Hello World"; //This CANNOT be null
String? myString = null; //This CAN be null
```

In your code, you will need to check if your `List<Homes>?` is null before using it.
You can use a null check `!` as:

```
List<Homes>? myOldList = null;
List<Homes> myNewList = myOldList!; //If myOldList is null, an Exception will be thrown.
List<Homes> myNewList = myOldList ?? []; //If myOldList is null, assign an empty list.
```

Or, in your FutureBuilder you should check if is not null.

```
if (snapshot.hasData) {
    if(snapshot.data != null){
        List<Homes> homelist = snapshot.data;
           return new CustomListView(homelist);
           //.......
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason for the error you're getting is that you're trying to assign a nullable value to a non-nullable. What you can do here is add null check or utilize the bang (!) operator when assigning the value to determine that the object is indeed non-null.